# App constantly needs to reload when I leave it and open it again, while other apps don't

Tags: iphone, ios, safari, applications, notes.app

I use DayOne app (https://dayoneapp.com/) for journaling on my iPhone 6s, and every time I leave the app and go back, even only after a few seconds, the app freezes and needs to reload, which sometimes can take more than 30 seconds.

At first, I thought that it's normal behavior because I left the app, so going in it again would obviously take some time. But over time I noticed that I hardly ever have the same issue with other apps, including Apple Notes and Safari.

If I leave Apple Notes or Safari for more than 5 minutes, sometimes it needs to reload but if I leave the app and go back after only a few seconds, it never needs to reload. But for DayOne, it still needs to reload even after a few seconds.

Do you maybe know what could cause this ? Any way to fix this issue ?

Comment: Did you reach out to DayOne support on this? They should be able to tell you whether this is expected behavior.

Comment: @nohillside The thing is, I thought maybe it's normal that Apple Notes and Safari don't behave like this because those are "native" apps, aren't they ?

Comment: They are, but this is most likely not the issue here.